# How can I set a conditional space succinctly in bash?

Tags: bash

I am simply modifying by `.bash_profile` file so it can display my current `git` branch. It works, but I just want to improve the formatting a bit.

Here is what I am currently doing:

`export PS1="${COL1}\u: ${COL2}\w${COL3} \$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2)${NCOL} > "`

If there is a branch present in the directly, it works properly. If there is no branch, the `2>/dev/null` will get rid of the error, however, there will be an awkward extra space present before and after the empty git branch because it is empty.

Is there an easy way to make this space only appear, without having to create a separate function that'll include/not include a space accordingly?

Comment: [That wheel was already invented.](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt) ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar I understand, came across it while searching. I just wanted to try it by myself because I'm learning bash as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the spaces in question part of the unconditional part of `PS1`, why not make them part of the `git` substitution?

```
export PS1="${COL1}\u: ${COL2}\w${COL3}\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 1 | sed 's/$/ /')${NCOL}> "
```

`colrm 1 1` instead of `colrm 1 2` keeps the leading space from the branch, e.g. `* master`.

`sed 's/$/ /'` replaces end-of-line with a space (and end-of-line). If `git branch` errors out, there is no line, so no space here either.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to build up the value of `PS1` from within `PROMPT_COMMAND` than to embed what amounts to a small script in `PS1` itself.

```
prompt_cmd () {
    PS1="${COL1}\u: ${COL2}\w${COL3}"
    git_info=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2)
    if [[ $git_info ]]; then
        PS1+="$git_info "
    fi
    PS1+="${NCOL} > "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

Just prior to displaying the prompt, the code stored in `PROMPT_COMMAND` (in this case, a single function call) is executed. `prompt_cmd` builds the value of `PS1` from scratch each time.

Comment: What does `if [[ $git_info ]]` do? Obviously, I understand the functionality, but I am not aware of how the double bracket notation expresses that.

Comment: It's short for `[[ -n $git_info ]]`, succeeding when the value of `$git_info` has non-zero length (i.e., also the same as `[[ $git_info != "" ]]`).